# C# How to Stop a WindowsMediaPlayer mp3 "Soundtrack" from playing that is on a different form

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, windows-media-player

My project is a Windows forms game with a mp3 soundtracks playing in the background, the soundtrack depends entirely on the gamestate/form that the player is in. Currently i have my "Introthemetune" soundtrack playing from launchscreen, however when the user eventually enters the "playing game state"/ new game i need the "Introthemetune" to stop so another one is able to play with no interference.

I know how to make the Introthemetune stop playing from inside the same Form it was instantiated using Introthemetune.controls.stop(). I've also tried accessing the class from the newly instantiated form with no success.

Code inside my LaunchScreen Form and the instantiated class -

WindowsMediaPlayer Introthemetune = new WindowsMediaPlayer();

```
    public LaunchScreen()
    {
        this.Opacity = 0;
        InitializeComponent();
        Introthemetune.URL = "Finalised Game Soundtrack.mp3";
    }
```

...

```
private void Gamescreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     Introthemetune.controls.play();
    }
```

I need this code to stop playing from outside of this form.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't stop it manually before showing the second form then the easiest way is to define `Introthemetune` as a `public static` variable in your form, say `MainForm`. Then you can access it from anywhere like `MainForm.Introthemetune.controls.stop()`

Comment: You're a legend didn't realise classes we are to be global. Thanks a bunch